# Is it possible to list all databases in Azure via REST API

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I need to receive list of existed databases in Microsoft Azure account. I do see REST API for example MySQL servers and databases, PostgeSQL servers and databases and so on. My question is there any action that lists all databases in one request or do I need to search them one by one? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can follow this URL `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/databases`

Comment: Will it show MySQL and PostgreSQL dabases as well as SQL ?

Comment: No only one kind of

Comment: Currently you have to search it according to server name so you cannot query all database together. you can each kind of server like Postgre with it server name so will get all listed database like this. Same for all.

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted to know. Only one by one for each server. Thanks

Comment: Yes, sure. If it'll help someone

Comment: Updated the answer please check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this REST API: [Resources - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list)

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?$filter={$filter}&api-version=2019-05-10
```

Add the $filter like this:

```
ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers' or ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases'
```

[image]

If you want to list other type of Azure SQL database, just follow the format above the filter.

**Note:**

If your resources are too more, you will need to call the API in the 'nextLink'.
[image]

Using the API can help you lists all databases in one request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My question is about ALL databases, not only SQL servers. Will it show MySQL and PostgreSQL dabases as well as SQL ?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev I updated my answer. Actually, it's possible to show MySQL and PostgreSQL databases or others  in one request.

Comment: Yeah, thanks it works. However there are almost no information that I need. So I am supposed I have to use it separately one by one. Thanks anyway for your help